Changing buttons on a frame after language change
I am trying to create a small game that allows the user to guess words. At this moment it is single language (Dutch) but I also want to allow French words so I've placed a listbox on the form that allows language selection.
For Dutch I only need 26 buttons (one for each letter) but for French I need 6 extra for the accented letters (all stored in a multidimensional array).
When the other language is selected I run a function that should remove all buttons and put the new version of the buttons on the frame.
I thought I could do this with this code:
    try:
    Btns = ButtonFrame.grid_slaves()
    for l in Btns:
        l.destroy()
    # print("Deleting buttons")
except:
    print("Error")

but this doesn't work, I always get a index out of range error for the letter array.
How can I dynamically change my buttons (add or subtract buttons from the frame)?

there is insufficient detail shown. provide a minimal-reproducible-example

It is better to post the full traceback as well.
